# Find out the number of MIMO streams with linux wireless command

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

It looks that `iw list` command gives the number of streams of the wifi interface that can be supported.

```
        VHT RX MCS set:
            1 streams: MCS 0-9
            2 streams: MCS 0-9
            3 streams: MCS 0-9
            4 streams: not supported
            5 streams: not supported
            6 streams: not supported
            7 streams: not supported
            8 streams: not supported
        VHT RX highest supported: 1300 Mbps
        VHT TX MCS set:
            1 streams: MCS 0-9
            2 streams: MCS 0-9
            3 streams: MCS 0-9
            4 streams: not supported
            5 streams: not supported
            6 streams: not supported
            7 streams: not supported
            8 streams: not supported
        VHT TX highest supported: 1300 Mbps
```

But how can I find the number of current streams which are actually using for the current association?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is a way, I haven't seen it yet. I use iw quite frequently these days, and use the "station dump"/"link" iw commands to see MCS rates to determine spatial streams. (using a table reference)

Please note, this will be somewhat of a generalization because you haven't actually listed what your card is. I wont go into 802.11ac (wave-2) or 802.11ax, you should be able to use these techniques for any 802.11 standard.

either mode/command will give you the MCS Rate, and you can reference that rate to get an idea of how many spatial streams are in use. if you are unsure if the AP you are trying to connect to has the same capabilities of your card you can use:

```
iw wlan0 scan | more
```

This is how I determine what the rate/streams actually are.

From a card/adapter acting as a Access-Point to stations:

```
iw dev wlan0 station dump
```

[image: openwrt AP-iw-sta-dump]

---

From a STA mode client connecting to an Acces-Point:

```
iw wlan1 link
```

[image: iw-wlan1sta-link]

---

### 802.11N

[image: 802.11n-mcs]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11n-2009

---

### 802.11AC

[image: 802.11ac-spatial-msc]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11ac-2013

if anyone reading this knows of an easier way to get the spatial stream number from iw, please let me know, i will update the answer. (and my usage of iw~!)

Comment: thank you for this answer, looks like there is no easy way at this moment.let me accept your answer, hope this can be possible someday.